# Delete Row Button for MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an admin panel where administrators can view all the data in a table, however I would like them to have a small delete button next to each row. Each row can be defined by an ID, however I am not sure about the code behind it.

```
        <!-- Requests -->
        <div class="panel panel-<?php echo $PColor; ?>">
        <table class="table table-striped table-requests">
            <thead class="table-requests">
              <tr>
                <th>Req ID</th>
                <th><?php echo "Song Name"; ?></th>
                <th><?php echo "Requested By"; ?></th>
                <th><?php echo "Comments (If any)"; ?></th>
                <th><?php echo "Time"; ?></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
<?php

      // Select Requests
      $SelectRequests = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `requests`");


      // Print Output
      foreach($SelectRequests as $PrintRequests)
      {
        echo 
        "
          <tr>
            <td><b>" . $PrintRequests['ID'] . "</b></td>
            <td>" . $PrintRequests['song'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $PrintRequests['name'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $PrintRequests['dedicated'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $PrintRequests['time'] . "</td>
        ";  
      }
    ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to have the delete button to the right of each displayed row, and make it functional?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: you'll need to use javascript /ajax to submit the id to a php script that handles the delete or have a form for each row with it's own button that posts the id to the same delete handling php script

Comment: You could also make the table inside a form and have a general submit button at the bottom. Give the user a checkbox instead of buttons and they can bulk delete.

Comment: If your rows have primary key values (or some unique value), you can take this value and do an href to another PHP file that will take the primary key value and delete the row from the table based on it.  The other file can have a query that says "delete from someTable where key=$key".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!-- Lets call this file index.php -->
<!-- Requests -->
<div class="panel panel-<?php echo $PColor; ?>">
<form action='deleteRecord.php' method='GET'>
<table class="table table-striped table-requests">
    <thead class="table-requests">
        <tr>
            <th>Req ID</th>
            <th><?php echo "Song Name"; ?></th>
            <th><?php echo "Requested By"; ?></th>
            <th><?php echo "Comments (If any)"; ?></th>
            <th><?php echo "Time"; ?></th>
            <!-- Add this for the table header -->
            <th><?php echo "Delete"; ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tbody>
<?php
// Select Requests
$SelectRequests = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `requests`");

// Print Output
foreach($SelectRequests as $PrintRequests){
    echo 
        "<tr>
            <td><b>" . $PrintRequests['ID'] . "</b></td>
            <td>" . $PrintRequests['song'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $PrintRequests['name'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $PrintRequests['dedicated'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $PrintRequests['time'] . "</td>
            <td><input type='checkbox' value ='" . $PrintRequests['ID'] . "' name='removal[]'></td>
        </tr>";  
  }
?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
```

deleteRecord.php

```
<?php
//Assume you can connect to DB
$removals = $_GET['removal'];
if(!empty($removals)){
    if(count($removals) > 1){
        $r = implode(', ', $removals);
        $query="DELETE from requests where ID IN (". $r . ")";
    } else {
        $query="DELETE from requests where ID = ". $removals[0];    
    }
    //Commit to db
} else {
    echo "Nothing Selected";
    //Handle an error if needed
}
//redirect

?>
```

Comment: In terms of deleteRecord.php: I have made the database connection with PDO, but how would I handle the query? Would I need to make an if statement or would it just work as is?

Comment: The edit should be what you need for the query. You may also want a check for no elements. I just assumed it would always have at least 1 here.

Comment: It's still not doing anything, this is what my page looks like: https://i.gyazo.com/a8579c2acb274d3de74c3cf1a756f9ed.png
I select the rows I want to delete and I hit submit but nothing is happening.

Comment: It does not look like the table was update so I am curious if you added the form at the top and bottom?

Comment: I just noticed that, I added the form and it redirects to the deleterecord.php file now with the correct link: "djpanel_beta/delete.php?removal=18&removal=19&removal=20" however nothing happens.

Comment: Here is an updated version of the delete code, as index.php works fine now: http://pastebin.com/ztdVL1Eu

Comment: you need to run the query something like $db->query($query); probably inside the if(count($removals < 0){} statement

Comment: You would need to do the query at the end after you create it. Where you call it there is nothing in $query. I added a comment for where it could go.

Comment: Can you do an output of what is in removals? See what that is getting you.

Comment: Can you try and do a rewrite of the entire deleteRecord.php? We'll see if that fixes it.

Comment: What is there has to be close. I am not sure of the DB structure and other factors that could be playing into it not working. At this point some troubleshooting on your end would probably be the most efficient for you.

Comment: The sign in my first check was backwards and apparently to get multiple inputs with the same name they have to have [] on the end. Everything was updated and I tested it with echos. the queries build correctly you just need to give it DB access

Comment: Good news is: The code actually works now!!
Bad news is: It only lets me delete 1 at a time

Comment: Did you update the name of the checkbox to be like this name='removal[]'

Answer (score 0):

try something like that :

```
<?php

      // Select Requests
      $SelectRequests = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `requests`");

      // Print Output
      foreach($SelectRequests as $PrintRequests)
      {
        echo 
        "
          <tr>
            <td><b>" . $PrintRequests['ID'] . "</b></td>
            <td>" . $PrintRequests['song'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $PrintRequests['name'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $PrintRequests['dedicated'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $PrintRequests['time'] . "</td>
            <td> <a href='delete.php?pid=" . $PrintRequests['ID'] . "'> Delete</a> </td>;
        ";  
      }
    ?>
```

In delete.php

```
 <?php
 // Connexion to database..
    $Query="delete from requests where id=".$_REQUEST['pid'];
    if(!mysqli_query($Conection,$Query)) {echo "<i>Error !</i>";}
echo '<script language="javascript"> document.location="Your_previous_page.php";</script>'; 
    ?>
```

Comment: Problem with this method is that I am using PDO, so SQL_query would not work in this situation, thanks anyway.